# NULL MPMediaitemPropertyAssetURL

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, avaudioplayer, mpmediaquery

Using MPMediaQuery and then getting the MPMediaitemPropertyAssetURL from the song results sometimes returns null (and by sometimes I mean in this case, 1/3 of the users song library).

Does anyone know what causes this? I'm assuming that this is due to some sort of DRM, but it isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: Having the same problem, I can confirm that it happens only on DRM'd files, but also can't find documentation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer can respond to your question :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6401317/536308

Answer (score 0):

MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL returns null for two possible reason.

1. The music is not downloaded to your device but added in music
   library only.
2. The music is loaded but its DRM-protected.

DRM-protected asset is not possible to play using AVPlayer, its only able to play using MPMusicPlayer. So you must need to check two things before proceed with AVPlayer.

1. MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL is nil ?
2. MPMediaItem is protected ?

Please see the code below….

```
MPMediaItem *theChosenSong = [[mediaItemCollection items] firstObject];
NSURL *assetURL = [theChosenSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

        if(assetURL) {
            BOOL bIsProtected = theChosenSong.protectedAsset;
            if(!bIsProtected) {
                // Do whatever you want to do
                NSLog(@"Its not protected");
           }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Its DRM protected");
            }
        }
        else {
                NSLog(@"Its DRM protected");
        }
```